# c# MultiThread a function each file line

Tags: c#, multithreading, indexing

So this is going to seem confusing
but I basically have a file like

```
username:password
username1:password4
username14:password114
```

Now I also have a function/void that looks like this

```
  public static void Login(string user, string pass)
```

Now the thing that the void does is make a httprequest and get the returning of it,

```
if (reqCookie.Equals("Error1"))
{
    //whenever the login credentials are false

}
else if (reqCookie.Equals("proxy"))
{
    //Whenever a captcha error get's returned it sets a proxy here
}
else
{
    //Whenever the request is successfull

}
```

I tried:

```
foreach (var line in AccountList)
{        
    new Task(() => {
        Console.WriteLine("LINE = " + accountline);
        string tocheck = AccountList[accountline];
        username = tocheck.Split(':')[0];
        password = tocheck.Split(':')[1];
        Login(username, password);
        accountline++;

    }).Start();        
}
```

But the problem with this is the fact that it keeps on checking the same account sadly

Do you guys know any solutions?

Comment: Why do you use `AccountList[accountline]` rather than `line`?

Comment: @TheGeneral That is not very helpful. KirriDev, note that acountline++ happens *within the task*!

Comment: @TheGeneral I'm trying to make an auto daily login thing for some game, no bruteforcing included

Comment: ```tocheck.Split(':')``` could be extracted into a local variable, for a little more performance

Comment: @FrankM Thanks, i'll keep that on a line but that's not the essential problem that I'm trying to fix here :(

Comment: where are username and password defined? might be as small as a missing var or two

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of luck or of how fast the task actually get started which result you get. Basically if all tasks arrive at this line at the same time:

```
string tocheck = AccountList[accountline];
```

then the variable `accountline` was not incremented once and has the same value for each task. This is why you sometimes get this result:

> But the problem with this is the fact that it keeps on checking the same account sadly

You should use `line` and forget about the indexing variable. This way each Task will get it's individual value to work with. Also you can `Split` only once and then distribute the values from the returned array

```
foreach (var line in AccountList)
{
    new Task(() =>
    {
        string [] temp = line.Split(':');
        username = temp[0];
        password = temp[1];
        Login(username, password);
    }).Start();
}
```

> This kinda worked, but it still sometimes uses the same username and pass...

Then may be you should pull out the string handling out of the Task method:

```
foreach (var line in AccountList)
{
    string [] temp = line.Split(':');
    username = temp[0];
    password = temp[1];
    Task.Run(() => Login(username, password));
}
```

you could also use [Parallel.ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop) to accomplish what you want:

```
Parallel.ForEach(AccountList, line => 
{
    string [] temp = line.Split(':');
    username = temp[0];
    password = temp[1];
    Login(username, password);
});
```

Comment: i might be wrong, but shouldn't you capture line in a local variable before handing it down to a closure?

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 if you would use a normal for-loop then yes, you need to do that, otherwise you run into out of bound because the indexing variable of the loop will have a value outside of the ranges of the collection due to closure. But foreach make this stuff actually possible

Comment: @KirriDev I made an edit, have a look. Are you sure that you don't have any double entries in your collection ?=!

Comment: @KirriDev you can also use `Parallel.ForEach` it is build for scenarios like yours. I posted an example

Comment: @KirriDev If my answer helped you to solve your problem, you might consider to mark it as accepted. If you don't know how to do it [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) can help.